# Did Israel allow newborn babies to starve to death in their cribs when they seized al-Nasr Hospital in 2023?

Tags: israel-hamas-war

On November 10, 2023, Israel seized Al-Nasr Hospital in Gaza City and ordered all doctors and staff to leave. (According to [an ICRC statement](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-12807335/Shocking-video-filmed-abandoned-Al-Nasr-Hospital-allegedly-shows-bodies-babies-left-die-city-besieged-IDF.html), the Red Cross had no part in the evacuation.)

[A video taken by the Emirati TV channel Al-Mashhad](https://www.middleeasteye.net/news/israel-palestine-war-gaza-dead-premature-babies-nasr-hospital) purports to show the decomposing corpses of infants. It is claimed that Israel allowed the babies to starve to death.

The only news source I can currently find for this in English is Middle East Eye, reporting on the video taken by Al-Mashhad. Did Israel actually do this?

Comment: Well, there are more sources in English now e.g. https://www.newarab.com/news/israel-left-premature-babies-die-alone-gaza-hospital but they all use the same video/claim. "The Israeli army said it was unable to immediately comment on the matter when contacted by AFP." https://www.ndtv.com/world-news/5-premature-babies-found-dead-at-gaza-hospital-during-truce-says-hamas-4618758

Comment: I guess we're operating on the assumption that this will be investigated -- I've now seen a Daily Mail article but still no comment from ICRC or IDF.

Comment: @Avery: More the assumption that unless it is investigated, we have no way of answering here.

Comment: I think this has now been resolved by this NBC report. Although the IDF denies responsibility, their answer combined with the input of the NGOs operating in the territory provides a conclusive answer. https://www.nbcnews.com/news/amp/rcna127533

Comment: @Avery the NGOs in the area are not quite unbiased, considering that arguing on Hamas claim may result in them getting shut down or worse.

Comment: @TheAsh Really? I think arguing on Israel is far more probable to get you in trouble. Israel has banned [more than 400 NGOs](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2022/8/19/what-are-the-palestinian-ngos-that-israel-shut-down) through its history, mainly Palestinians, but also some jewish ones, and has moved to block many [international ones](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2018/jan/07/israel-imposes-travel-ban-on-20-foreign-ngos-over-boycott-movement).

Comment: I guess this will remain closed, but please check out this WaPo article as well. (Paywall lifted) http://wapo.st/47GKLm8

Comment: @Rekesoft I'm not sure what you are driving at. That a government of terrorists may be inhospitable to NGOs who don't toe their line is hardly a surprise. Israel's treatment has nothing to do with it. Tbe fact that Israel does not treat NGOs well doesn't mean that Hamas does! It's not a binary.

Comment: @TheAsh That a government of terrorist may be inhospitable to NGOs who don't toe their line _wouldn't be_ hardly a surprise... but is it? Honestly, I don't know how many NGOs Hamas has banned, or tried to expel from Gaza. You're just assuming they do.